How can I modify this Python to to return a Property ID on Redfin, given addresses?
I am trying write and run Python code on Google Colaboratory. I want use this Redfin scraper (https://apify.com/tri_angle/redfin-search) to pull a property ID for a given list of addresses. The code reformats my list of addresses into Latitude/Longitude coordinates which can be used to locate the property and its ID. I have an API token I've plugged into the code and there doesn't appear to be issues. But it doesn't return any information?

In my code, you can see a Texas address at the bottom. I would be expecting information returned such as a property ID. Is this a code issue? Is Colaboratory not able to run Python like I thought?
import requests
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
import json
import time

APIFY_API_URL = 'https://api.apify.com/v2/acts/tri_angle~redfin-search/runs?token=***'  # Plug in the provided API URL

def geocode_address(address):
    geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="redfin_scraper", timeout=10)  # Increased timeout to 10 seconds
    try:
        location = geolocator.geocode(address)
        if location:
            return location.latitude, location.longitude
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error geocoding address {address}: {e}")
    return None, None

def search_redfin(lat, lng):
    search_url = f"https://www.redfin.com/stingray/do/location-autocomplete?location={lat},{lng}"
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
    response = requests.get(search_url, headers=headers)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        try:
            json_text = response.text.split('&&')[1]
            return json.loads(json_text)
        except (json.JSONDecodeError, IndexError) as e:
            print("Error decoding JSON response:", e)
            print("Response text:", response.text)
            return None
    return None

def extract_home_id(search_results):
    try:
        payload = search_results.get('payload')
        if not payload:
            return None
        region_views = payload.get('regionViews')
        if not region_views:
            return None
        root = region_views.get('__root')
        if not root:
            return None
        for result in root:
            if 'home' in result:
                return result['home']['id']
    except KeyError as e:
        print(f"KeyError: {e}")
    return None

def construct_redfin_detail_url(state, city, street, zip_code, home_id):
    street_formatted = street.replace(' ', '-')
    city_formatted = city.replace(' ', '-')
    return f"https://www.redfin.com/{state}/{city_formatted}/{street_formatted}/home/{home_id}"

def query_apify_redfin_scraper(detail_url):
    api_url = APIFY_API_URL
    payload = {
        "detailUrls": [{"url": detail_url}],
        "debugLog": False
    }
    headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
    response = requests.post(api_url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(payload))
    if response.status_code == 201:
        try:
            return response.json()['data']['id']
        except json.JSONDecodeError as e:
            print("Error decoding JSON response:", e)
            print("Response text:", response.text)
            return None
    return None

def get_apify_scraper_results(run_id):
    api_url = f"https://api.apify.com/v2/acts/tri_angle~redfin-search/run-sync-get-dataset-items?token=***"
    while True:
        response = requests.get(api_url)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            try:
                data = response.json()
                if data:
                    return data
            except json.JSONDecodeError as e:
                print("Error decoding JSON response:", e)
                print("Response text:", response.text)
                return None
        time.sleep(10)  # Wait for 10 seconds before retrying
    return None

def main(addresses):
    results = []
    for address in addresses:
        lat, lng = geocode_address(address)
        if lat and lng:
            search_results = search_redfin(lat, lng)
            if search_results:
                home_id = extract_home_id(search_results)
                if home_id:
                    parts = address.split(',')
                    street = parts[0].strip()
                    city = parts[1].strip()
                    state_zip = parts[2].strip().split(' ')
                    state = state_zip[0]
                    zip_code = state_zip[1]
                    detail_url = construct_redfin_detail_url(state, city, street, zip_code, home_id)
                    run_id = query_apify_redfin_scraper(detail_url)
                    if run_id:
                        scraper_results = get_apify_scraper_results(run_id)
                        results.append(scraper_results)
    return results

addresses = [
    "10725 Lone Pine Ln, Fort Worth, TX 76108",
    # Add more addresses here
]

detail_urls = main(addresses)
print(json.dumps(detail_urls, indent=2))`


I can't say about Google Colab, because I have no experience with it.
It seems to me that you are running the actor twice, calling query_apify_redfin_scraper and get_apify_scraper_results in your main function, without actually using the passed run_id.
You should definitely make only the second call, using a POST request instead of a GET, and passing the correct input like in the first call. See the documentation for the API endpoint.
Then, you can monitor the run and check if it actually produced results from the Apify platform.
I also have two suggestions:

For a simpler API usage, take a look at the Python client.
You can pass the address directly to the Redfin Search scraper without the need of geocoding, even tho results may vary, since it uses a different Redfin API. To do this, put these properties in the input:

{
    "offerTypes": [
        "sale",
        "rent"
    ],
    "searchLocation": "10725 Lone Pine Ln, Fort Worth, TX 76108",
    "searchMatches": 5
}

Hope this helps!

Thanks Marco. I'm not a coder or programmer so this is really difficult. What I'd really like to figure out is how to retrieve a full URL from zilllow or redfin given a .xlsx of addresses. With a full URL for each address, I can use Excel power query to do the rest. The issue is that each property has a unique identifer at the end of the url (ie ZPID in zillow). Without knowing the identifier, I can't construct a complete URL

I will add a second, less technical answer.
What I would suggest doing is to use the scraper from the console, here: https://console.apify.com/actors/fSNRlNbcFgtHBFBE9/input. You can input one address directly under "Get more search URLs" → "Location to search" and check if the output satisfies you. You should do this for each address you have. Here is a screenshot.
If you want to automatize this process, you should call this endpoint: https://api.apify.com/v2/acts/tri_angle~redfin-search/run-sync-get-dataset-items?token=***, passing the following payload:
{
    "debugLog": false,
    "maxResults": 100,
    "offerTypes": [
        "sale",
        "rent"
    ],
    "searchLocation": "The address...", <-- your address here
    "searchMatches": 100, <-- how many results you want
    "zoomIn": true
}

and with headers:
Content-Type:application/json

You will receive the same output you saw on the console as a response.
